# How to measure the load generated by a web application on the user environment?

Tags: performance, frontend, cpu, cpu-usage, virtualization

I have an old legacy service for benchmarking a load produced by html5-pages to the users hardware. Here is a high-level idea: we want to be sure that some specific web-page will not freeze users browser and laptop with heavy CPU load.

The way it is implemented now: there is a physical laptop (sic!) in the office with the python script, which takes some html-file (let's omit a description of the way the file gets to this laptop for simplification) and opens it in Google Chrome (in headless mode) and makes 100 CPU measurements per second during 30 seconds interval.

The most important part of measurement function (simplified):

```
for p in psutil.process_iter():
    cpu_percent = p.cpu_percent(interval=collect_stats_interval)
```

So the key idea is quite simple: we have kind of "average" users laptop, and we open some page in most popular browser in this laptop. And if on this laptop with this page opened the CPU load is below 40%, it means that on the average users laptop this page will also generate nearly the same load and it is ok.

In other words, if we opened this page on our laptop and it is ok, the users laptop will be ok too.

And now I have to move this code to a bit more solid and robust infrastructure than a laptop in office. AND, it is crucial, to keep measurements proportions.
 I mean, if some html5 page had been benchmarked to 35%, on the new infrastructure we need to approximate all results. Like "On this brand new high-performance server this page has been benchmarked to 5% CPU usage, and so it means that on a simple users laptop (old approach) this page will make 35% CPU load".

But here is the first problem: it seems like I cannot use this approach inside any kind of virtual infrastructure and keep measurements stable.
 I've tried to run this service inside a docker and despite all tricks with cpu limits all I've got is unstable and big measurements range: first time it is 20%, than -40%, next time - 33%.
 And since on the laptop (without any virtualisation) this service worked well and always provided stable measurements, I believe that the key problem is virtualisation.

I think so because dedicated virtual machine with Ubuntu without docker had provided me with nothing more than the same unstable bunch of measurements.

And that's why I have the second problem: without stable measurements I cannot develop some new-to-old mapping method. 
Also I'm not good at system programming so I have no clear understanding of CPU load concept. I mean, what I have to measure to be sure that some software makes "moderate" CPU load on some users hardware? Maybe there is a better and robust way to measure this metric - maybe CPU time, maybe something else.

And (finally!) here is the question: what is the most robust and portable way to measure CPU load across bare metal hardware and some k8s/virtual machine? What I have to measure and how?

Comment: Docker should not make much of a difference (modulo cgroups limitations) because a containerized process is just a process running with different namespaces. Virtualization should should be workable, I mean a vCPU is not shared as long as the guest is running. Virtualization fo the video could slow things down and make them fluctuate a bit but not as much as you noted. Maybe there's something wrong with the measurement? Also note that measuring CPU utilization is kind of misleading. For example the following loop `.loop: / pause / jmp .loop` will utilize 100% of the CPU ...

Comment: ... as far as the scheduler is concerned but it's actually using very limited resources on that core. Also servers' CPUs are not very different from client CPUs. Yes, they have more advanced extensions but if Chrome was not compiled to use them it won't have much of a speed up in a server. Especially since JS is not multithreaded without WebWorkers. Sure server CPUs have higher boost frequency but by how much? So If you use Chrome compiled for a client CPU and, just to be sure, cap the max frequency, you should get similar results. Finally, ...

Comment: ... maybe power/energy consumed may be a better estimator of CPU usage? Some Intel CPU support RAPL that would give you this information. One more thing: usually one benchmarks a system by profiling it (including timing it), doesn't Chrome have anything for that?

Comment: Instead of checking the CPU load, perhaps it would be wiser to use Selenium: with a script, you can simulate user actions and measure times to check that the web page is responsive.

Comment: On which operating system do you need to perform these measurements?

Comment: @AlexO I believe that Centos is a default option for me.

Comment: @ipStack yep, I thought about Selenium, but I'm afraid I need more precise approach. Just because in my case any UI lags are far beyond the acceptable level of lagging for me.

Comment: @MargaretBloom thanks for your answer! It looks like it makes sense for me to re-benchmark my docker approach, if I got your idea right.

Comment: @MargaretBloom also I've found Perf Monitor in Chrome Dev Tools. Maybe I'll find some underlying utils in Chromium to extract them and use from CLI. https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-64/#perf-monitor

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think you're right with this point:

> I cannot use this approach inside any kind of virtual infrastructure

If you're running on virtual infrastructure, then a hypervisor determines the amount of CPU cycles that your test environment can use. From *within* the test system, you can neither tell the number of "real" CPU cycles that you consumed, nor the total number of CPU resources that were potentially available for your system.

That is, in general, you will need to **check the CPU load measurement features  offered by the hypervisor that provides your virtual infrastructure**. Your other option is sticking with physical infrastructure.

(Virtualization in this context applies to virtual *infrastructure*. If you're running containers on *physical* infrastructure then the load measurement situation will be straightforward, but I understood that this is not your current setup.)